# Service starts but doesn't keep running

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm running `Node.js` and `MongoDB` on an `Amazon EC2` instance.

Everything works perfectly if I run `sudo mongod`. I want to be able to close my ssh connection and have it still run, though, so I've been trying to get it going as a service.

I've changed the config so the db path is `/data/db` and done `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db`. Everything looks right permissions-wise when I do `la -l`.

When I try `sudo service mongodb start`, it says `mongod start/running, process 4805`, but that process is nowhere to be found in `top` (and, obviously, my app isn't hitting the db, or there would be no problem).

Trying without `sudo`, just `service mongodb start`, yields

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.35" (uid=1000 pid=4809 comm="start mongod ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")`
```

I've tried `mongod --repair` as suggested in another question.

Everything else I'm seeing says it's a permissions issue, but the `chown` seems to have worked?

No idea what the `Rejected send message` is about.

Comment: Have you checked the mongodb log itself?